# Weird fonts showing which are coming from database

Tags: php, theme-development, mysql

Recently my website was hacked. Then I recovered it and uploaded files to server. But I can see there are lot of weird fonts showing in the site like headers, footers, contents etc. I am not sure what is going on. The language of the site is Bengali as well as it's content. UTF-8 is provided in the header so that it can show Bengali. Please a have look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have an encoding issue, at some point you stored your data in a format that isn't capable of storing it, and the characters got mangled/broken. You need to check that your database tables can actually store UTF-8 multibyte encoded data, otherwise it doesn't matter how often you tell the client it is UTF-8, because it isn't ( it used to be, but not anymore ). Once you've fixed this you're going to have to redo your import. Otherwise there is not enough information to pinpoint the exact cause, we can only speculate

Comment: For clarification, that's not a font, it's a character, if you take a multibyte character and store in a single byte format, it becomes 2 characters, or the additional bytes get truncated. That's what you're seeing here